# urls-views-template tags error on the django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

i have three pages(views,urls,templates) one with artist list with all posts one with artist details from the main list.
first and second pages work fine,but i have problem on the third page i want from the artists details to go the third
page and i take more details for the director where is a foreign key on the artist.
but not work and dont show me error if i click on the director then go me on the top from my artist details
if i written on my browser 127/...../dir/1 then go me on the third page but i cant go from the second page template tag..

that my code

my model

```
class artist(models.Model):
    director = models.ForeignKey('Director')
    ..................

class Director(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    ..............................
```

my view

```
def view_dir(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Director, pk=pk)
    return render_to_response('blog/director_details.html', {
        'post': post
    })
```

my urls

```
url(r'^view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', views.view_post, name='view_post'), #artists details
url(r'^dir/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.view_dir, name='view_dir'),
```

template tag in the artist details

`<p><a href="/dir/{{ director.id }}">{{post.director}}</a></p>` #artists details

Comment: Care to tell us what that error is?

Comment: Use `<p><a href="{% url 'view_dir' pk=director.id %}">{{post.director}}</a></p>`

Comment: the problem is i cant with template tags to go on the thrind page=view_dir

Comment: if i use '<p><a href="{% url 'view_dir' pk=director.id %}">{{post.director}}</a></p>' then shoe me error 'NoReverseMatch at /view/hateful-eight/
Reverse for 'view_dir' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dir/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']'

Comment: What is the pk of your director? by the looks of it you've overridden it

Comment: i not have define pk for director

Answer (score 0):

Your template tag should be :

```
<p><a href="{% url 'view_dir' post.director.id %}">{{post.director}}</a></p>
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /view/post-one/
Reverse for 'view_dir' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<pk>\\d+)/$'] i take that error

Comment: @user27818 are you sure that director is an actual object that has id? or should it be post.director.id?

Comment: yeah now work thnx you so much post.director.id is a correct thnx you

Comment: @user27818 if you found the answer to be correct, please mark it as so by clicking on the tick mark. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if i use for template tag `<p><a href='{% url 'view_dir' post.director.id %}'>{{post.director}}</a></p>`then work fine the problem They were `post.director.id`use post front director.id because the tag in inside at posts details if not inside then not use post thnx you @Bogdan Goie